# "Незавершенное строительствО" или "незавершенное строительствОМ"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, грамматика

Как правильно?

> ...а также обследование здания БПК (незавершенное строительством) под лечебно-физкультурный комплекс...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Для того,чтобы дать полный ответ, нужно видеть весь контекст.

Comment: Нашел в Сети. Это выписка из решения арбитражного суда. Весь текст не доступен. Судя по частям, приносимым Гуглом, там полно ошибок. Есть ли смысл этот текст редактировать?

Answer (score 2):

Это термин, который определяется следующим образом:

**Законченный строительством объект** ― объект, на котором выполнены и приняты в соответствии с требованиями проекта и нормативных документов все строительно-монтажные работы, а также пуско-наладочные и другие работы по подготовке его к вводу в эксплуатацию.

[Законченный строительством объект | academic.ru](http://normative_reference_dictionary.academic.ru/19204/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)

Comment: А как правильно в итоге?

Comment: Строительство - многозначное слово, можно предположить, что в данной терминологии это "строительная организация", тогда получается "законченный строительной организацией объект". СТРОИТЕЛЬСТВО,  ср.  2.  // ОРГАНИЗАЦИЯ, учреждение, занимающиеся возведением зданий, сооружений. Начальник строительства.

Answer (score 1):

Если можно, лучше перефразировать:

Обследование здания БПК (недостроенного)
Или
Обследование здания БПК (строительство не завершено)

Если поменять выражение в скобках нельзя, используйте "незавершенное строительство".

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на то, что есть такие профессиональные термины: "законченный строительством объект", "завершенный строительством объект". Примеров много в Сети. Вот один из них: [Порядок приемки и ввода в эксплуатацию законченных строительством объектов](http://www.ispoldoc.ru/17st.html)

Comment: А как правильно в итоге?

Comment: @Aer  Для того,чтобы дать полный ответ, нужно видеть весь контекст. Надеюсь, автор вопроса дополнит его.